# Wrap special characters in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string which contains only special characters like

```
var str="~`!@#$%%%";
```

I want to wrap this string in jquery like,`$(str)`.
But it is throwing an error.
How can i wrap special characters in jquery?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You can't 'wrap a string in jQuery'. What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: have a look here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: `$(str)` requires `str` to be either a selector expression, or HTML beginning with a `<tag>`.

Comment: i have a textbox , where the user can type some input.I want to know whether the user entered text or html. I am wrapping the input  value in jquery and checking if $(str).contents().length >0

Comment: `$("#textbox").val(str)`

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, if you want to test whether jQuery some parse a string (i.e. is it HTML) you can put a try block around the parse attempt - if an error is thrown there is no HTML

```
var text = '~`!@#$%%%';
try
{
    $(text);
    console.log('html');
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log('no html');
}
```

This is quite basic you may have to do further checks based on what sort of logic you need to implement but generally if jQuery cannot parse it it's not HTML